# How to display double or float in graphview android?

Tags: android

I need to make a graph of decimal numbers(float or double) and I am using the GraphView jjoe64 library.

When I do this The chart is not represented:

```
LineGraphSeries series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[]{
                    new DataPoint(0.5, 0.1)
            });
```

Comment: Did you get any solution to display float in BarGraph?

Comment: If I am not wrong, the graph's libraries are designed for double and integer type, but not supports float. When I try to parse float to change into double, graph didn't plot. So, there is no solution I think to plot a number like 12.34 into the graph.

Answer (score -1):

Add to xml this

```
 <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:title="Graph Title"
        android:id="@+id/graph"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linetext"/>
```

And this code:

```
GraphView line_graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
   LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> line_series =
           new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
           new DataPoint(0, 1),
           new DataPoint(1, 5),
           new DataPoint(2, 3),
           new DataPoint(3, 2),
           new DataPoint(4, 6)
   });
   line_graph.addSeries(line_series);
```

Comment: Well, but when I try to add float or double numbers It doesn't work, this was my question.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

For reporters, if you believe it is a bad or wrong answer, downvote it.

Answer (score -1):

This is worked solution for me using Float variables:

Define the variables before onCreate:

```
public static float x1, y1 = 0;
public static float x2, y2 = 0;
public static float x3, y3 = 0;
```

After OnCreate use this code below:

```
try { //I use Try-Catch on here for not get an app crash
PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new PointsGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[]{  //You can also use LineGraphSeries if you want to

        new DataPoint( x3, y3), //Your variables were defined above.
        new DataPoint( x2, y2),
        new DataPoint( x1, y1)


});
graph.addSeries(series); //Put those variables into "graph"

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
}
```